# Why is bitwise compliment of 1 in -2

Tags: c#

I am trying some bitwise operators in C#, not sure how compliment calculates output as -2 for 1

If i represent 1 in 8 bit binary

1 = 00000001

~1 =11111110 = How come this evaluates to be -2?

```
    Sample code that i am using in C#


    //Bitwise Compliment
    //1  = 00000001
    //~1 = 11111110 = -2
    Console.WriteLine(~1);
```

Comment: If you put "binary negative number" to the google you would find billions of articles. And I'm actually wondered you think no one ever wrote an article about that.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations
Look at Two's Complement.
You're using a signed number. In order to represent negative numbers, many systems use two's complement.

Comment: [Negative binary numbers](http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/vol_4/chpt_2/3.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well... What do you hope it to be? Since we are using the **two-complements** representation this is simply how it is:

```
00000011 = 3
00000010 = 2
00000001 = 1
00000000 = 0
11111111 = -1
11111110 = -2
11111101 = -3
11111100 = -4
```

If we would use the **one-complient** representation, we would have this list, and then you would be right:

```
00000011 = 3
00000010 = 2
00000001 = 1
00000000 = 0
11111111 = -0 <== Watch this!!!
11111110 = -1
11111101 = -2
11111100 = -3
```

Since the computerbuilders decided not to have a negative zero, they created the two-complements representation.

If you do a bitwise complement, all bits are reversed. So `00000001` will result in `11111110` and that is simply -2 (when using two-complements).

Are you looking for the negate operator `-`?

```
Console.WriteLine(-1);
```

BTW: De complement negate operator is the same as the complement operator plus one (when using the two-compliment representation).

So:

```
-x == ~x + 1;
```

For more info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations

Comment: OK can you tell me in 11111110 , the first digit from right is the sign bit so it means it's negative. Now should i calculate this 1111110 = (0+ 2+4 +8.. 7 times) to get the answer.

Comment: @Charu: When the bit 7 is set, it gets the value -128. So the formula would be: 2 + 4 + 8 + 16 + 32 + 64 -128.

Answer (score 3):

Negative `int` numbers in .NET are treated as [two's-complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement). That means that:

```
1111....111111 = -1
1111....111110 = -2
1111....111101 = -3
1111....111100 = -4
```

etc; basically, negative `x` is equal to `2`<sup>`base`</sup>`-x`

If you don't want negatives, use `uint` instead of `int`

Answer (score 1):

.NET (and most languages) use [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twos_complement) to represent negative numbers.  In the simplest explanation, this is found by taking the [one's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones%27_complement) (which involves reversing each bit) and then adding `1`.

Your inversion creates the one's complement, which is interpreted one *lower* than the two's complement.

Answer (score 0):

Signed integers in most computing contexts (including signed integers in C#: `sbyte`, `short`, `int`, and `long`) are represented using the [Two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) representation. In this, the first bit indicates the sign, and the rest indicates the number. (0..127 counts from 0000 0000..0111 1111, and -128..-1 counts from 1000 0000..1111 1111)

What you might've been expecting is what you'd get with the bitwise compliment of an unsigned int:

```
uint b = 1;
uint a = (uint)~b;
// a == 4294967294, which is 2^32-2, or in binary,
// 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111110
```

Answer (score 0):

If your eight bits represent a signed value then is only bits 1-7 that represent the number, bit 8 indicates whether the number is positive (0) or negative (1).

To get your desired behaviour you must use an unsigned type.

Answer (score 0):

Because using Two's Complement, you invert all of the bits, and add one. So this is the entire process:

```
11111110 ; start
00000001 ; invert
00000010 ; add one
```

Source: [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, [`~`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/d2bd4x66%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) operators works like

```
~x = -x - 1
```

In .NET, negative integers called with [*twos-complement*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)

```
11111111 = -1
11111110 = -2
```